# connection between python server and java client

Tags: java, python, sockets, client, client-server

im trying to create a connection between a python server and java client (which is in android) the idea is that only the client sends data to the server and the server will handle things. however ,  the problem is that The first time message is sent, server receives the message; and then, when time I'm trying to send the next msg. server is not receiving anything.

the server is very simple: here is a snippest:

```
server_socket = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
server_socket.bind((HOST, PORT))
server_socket.listen(10)
client_socket, client_address = server_socket.accept()
print 'Connect with ' + client_address[0]

while check_if_directx_game():
    data = client_socket.recv(1024).decode("UTF-8")
    if 'SBA' in data:
        PressKey(a)
    if "PBA" in data:
        ReleaseKey(a)
    else:
        print data
        print "was here"

client_socket.close()
server_socket.close()
```

the client side:

```
public class SendMessage extends AsyncTask<String,Void,Void>{
private Exception exception;
@Override
protected Void doInBackground(String... params){
    try {
        try {
            Socket socket = new Socket("192.168.1.178", 9000);
            PrintWriter ToServer = new PrintWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(socket.getOutputStream()));
            ToServer.print(params[0]);
            ToServer.flush();
            ToServer.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        this.exception = e;
        return null;
    }
    return null;
}}
```

i only recieve from the client the SBA msg but never recives the PBA  that sends exacly after that. i closed the PrintWriter after the flush();

P.S. -- when i print data in the server after the first time it only print new line and than the " was here" string

any ideas ?

Comment: It looks like your client is connecting, sending a message, and then disconnecting each time you want to send a message. But your server is doing a single accept and trying to read from the same socket forever. If you want a new connection for each message, you need a new accept for each message; if you want to keep using be same socket, you have to do that on both sides.

Comment: By the way, if you _do_ want to keep using the same socket, you need to use some kind of framing protocol, not just assume that each `send` on one side will show up as a single `recv` on the other side. A TCP socket is just a stream of bytes, not a stream of messages. (The worst thing is that when you’re testing things with small messages on localhost when the machine isn’t busy, it’ll almost always work, misleading you into thinking the code is correct, but then failing most of the time when you deploy it for real.)

Comment: i do actually want to keep the same socket however, im new to java so its a client i found on the net and i added the sending. i thought it was wierd either . every time i want to send to create new socket after using sendmessage.excute(string..)

Comment: can u give me another advice on how to set this up its the mose important thing left to be dont in my project.

Comment: If you want to reuse the same socket, you need to rearrange your Java code so you open the socket and streamwriter once, hold onto them, and reuse them in each `SendMessage` task. I'm sure there are good samples of that online, but I have no idea where to find them.

Comment: As for framing—the simplest option, is just separating messages with newlines. That does mean you need to escape any newlines in your messages (unless there just can never be one), but other than that, the client side is just something like `ToServer.print(params[0] + "\n");` (or however you do string concat in Java), and the server side can just use `for data in client_socket.makefile(encoding='utf-8'):`. (You're also going to want some error handling, reconnect logic, etc., but that will get you started.)

Comment: do u think that by changing the server to be threaded it will solve the problem ? i prefer finding a python solution instead of java.

Comment: abarnert already pointed out most of the issues.I just want to clarify that you have to take care of certain situations by multithreading your application. For instance you could run the `server_socket.accept()` in it's own thread wich will spawn a new thread that will handle the connection. However each new thread will have it's own client socket. If you don't change the java code this will lead to [half-open](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2009/05/detection-of-half-open-dropped.html) connection since the server won't notice that  the client died.